# Show only if a ViewModel has value in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have this class and many properties in it

```
    public class Course
    {
      public int CourseId { get; set; }
      public string CourseName { get; set; }
      public Universities? UniversityName { get; set;}
      public string Summary { get; set; }
      *
      *
    }
```

View Model looks like this

```
    public class DetailsViewModels
    {
      public Course DetailsVMCourse;
      public string PageTitle;
      *
    }
```

And controller

```
    public IActionResult CourseDetails(int id)
    {
        DetailsViewModels detailsViewModels = new DetailsViewModels()
        {
            //loads the course to the view model from a test database
            DetailsVMCourse = _courseRepository.FindCourse(id)
        };
        return View(detailsViewModels);
    }
```

I want to show only if a model property has value in the view. 
At the moment I am doing this on the view page for each property..

```
@{ if (Model.DetailsVMCourse.Summary != null)
  {
   <h4>Cource summary</h4>
   <p>
   @Model.DetailsVMCourse.Summary
   </p>
  }
}
```

Rather than checking every single property with *!=null* in view, what would be better and efficient way. This is my first project so your help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: You would check it in the view as you are doing now. Or you can check it before you return from the action and can select a different view based on the model's result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write something that would loop over every property in the class using reflection, but I'm thinking you really don't want that.  The properties are of different types and I am sure there are some you may not actually want to show (IDs?).  With some being other classes, it gets complicated (UniversityName is an object, not a string).  Also, within your H4 Tag, the "title" is not the same as the property, it's more human-readable.  So I think your best bet is to follow your current pattern and have a block for each property that you really want to show, along with its human-readable title.

My only other suggestion would be to use IsNullOrWhiteSpace() instead of the null check for the string properties.  It's a cleaner/thorough check for strings:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.DetailsVMCourse.Summary))
```

Comment: You are correct, dont want to use reflection, as my properties are different types. Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: @aries, no problem.  If you feel this is an adequate answer, please mark this as the answer to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

I would use reflection to get the properties that have a value that is not equal to null, and then use a loop to display the properties and its values.

```cs
var populatedProperties = Model.DetailsVMCourse.GetType().GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.GetValue(Model.DetailsVMCourse) != null);

foreach (var prop in populatedProperties){
   <h4>@prop.Name</h4>
   <p>
   @prop.GetValue(Model.DetailsVMCourse);
   </p>
}
```

Comment: Although properties are different types, but I can use this in a different class. Thanks for the idea. 